# Can't log into Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't log into minecraft launcher or the website. When I use forgot password, it won't send me the email. I've had my account for a long time now..

Comment: Your question seem to be very vague and it's already asked.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague..

The only things that I can think of are:

**"It won't send me the email.":** Do you still have access to your email account and, have you migrated your Minecraft credentials into a Mojang account?
*If not, it may be a good idea to contact Mojang for support.*

**"I can't log into <s>Minecraft launcher or</s> the website":** Definitely sounds like you've forgotten to migrate your account, or that your password is wrong.

---

You migrate your account at: https://account.mojang.com/migrate
However, if you have forgotten your password - [Contact Mojang support](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new) with proof of purchase etc. (More info [here](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/797301-account-security-questions))

Comment: Yes, I still have access to my email account and I have migrated already. My password is definitely right though.

Comment: Have you tried '[resetting](https://account.mojang.com/password)' your password to your account? Because I doubt that it's correct.

Comment: I have tried that. It's not sending me an email though..

Comment: Maybe you're using the wrong email. Because that would be the only reasons it wouldn't arrive. Did you use your own email or your friend's email? If not, you may want to contact Mojang to help you get back onto your account. (As in get the details and reset the password, if needed). Remember to include proof of purchase, such as your transaction IDs etc, which is in your email confirming the purchase of your Minecraft account (turning it from "Free" to "Premium").